# instagram likes count shown when hover the mouse on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get the count of Instagram like into my instafeed?

I want to look get the result like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxy86.jpg)

when mouse hover the image, the like count will appear,

what codes need to be added here in my work?:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  Instafeed.prototype._makeTemplate = function (template, data) {
    var output, pattern, varName, varValue, _ref;
    pattern = /(?:\#{2})([\w\[\]\.]+)(?:\#{2})/;
    output = template;
    while (pattern.test(output)) {
      varName = output.match(pattern)[1];
      varValue = (_ref = this._getObjectProperty(data, varName)) != null ? _ref : '';
      output = output.replace(pattern, "" + varValue);
    }
    return output;
  };
  
  //<a href="##link##"> // original image link
     
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed',
    get: 'user',
    userId: 8303117,
 accessToken: '8303117.467ede5.360077337739443ab81ddc05f94ef38d',
    tagName: '{{settings.instafeed_tags}}',
    limit: 8,
    links: true,
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    clientId: '{{settings.instafeed_client_id}}',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    template: '<div class="cus-col-md-3" style="padding:0;"><a href="##link##" target="_blank" class="zoom" style="background-image: url(##image##);"></a></div>',
    after: function() {
      
      if (!this.hasNext()) {
 
      }
      
    },
    before: function () {
      
      $('#instafeed').empty();
      
    },
  });
  
  $(document).find('.livery-instafeed-navigation').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
   feed.next();
   e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  feed.run();
  /*userId: 8303117
accessToken: 8303117.467ede5.360077337739443ab81ddc05f94ef38d
  
  */
  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done this myself. you can use this {{likes}} to get number of likes the image has.
You should put it in your instafeed template.

Replace this:

```
<div class="cus-col-md-3" style="padding:0;"><a href="##link##" target="_blank" class="zoom" style="background-image: url(##image##);"></a></div>
```

With this:

```
<div class="cus-col-md-3" style="padding:0;"><a href="##link##" target="_blank" class="zoom" style="background-image: url(##image##);"><div class="likes">{{likes}}</div></a></div>
```

And use CSS to place it where you want, hide it and show it on hover.

You can read more about templating instafeed here: 
https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js#templating

Hope this helps.

Comment: whats up :) thanks, adding {{like}}  is not working. :(